# How to send files(IFormFile) from Web Controller Action to API Controller Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iformfile

Let us say I want to upload some files.

My HTML Form in the Razor View looks like this:

```
@model SequereMe.Onboarding.Web.ViewModels.Branding.TenantBrandingViewModel
@{
}

<form asp-controller="BrandingSettings" asp-action="Save" asp-method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="TenantId" value=@Model.TenantId />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="logoFileUrl">Logo File Upload:</label>
        <input asp-for="LogoFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="logoFileUrl" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
        <h1>@Model.LogoFileUrl</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="backgroundFileUrl">Background File Upload:</label>
        <input asp-for="BackgroundFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="backgroundFileUrl" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
        <h1>@Model.BackgroundFileUrl</h1>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

The controller action this HTML form will hit on submit is this web controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(TenantBranding tenantBranding)
{
    var result =
        await _apiClient.PostAsync("/BrandingSettings", tenantBranding);

    switch (result.Status)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
            return new RedirectResult("~/Error/404");
        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
            //return View("Edit", result.Message.Content);
        default:
            return new RedirectResult("~/Error/500");
    } 
}
```

I am further using the FluentClient implementation of  Pathoschild.Http.Client.IClient interface to make an API Call to this Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] TenantBranding tenantBranding)
{
    if (tenantBranding == null)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid Parameter: The incoming tenantBranding parameter is null");
    }

    if (tenantBranding.TenantId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid Parameter: The tenantId in the incoming parameter tenantBranding is empty");
    }

    var result = _brandingLogic.Save(tenantBranding).Result;

    if (!result)
    {
        return new JsonResult(500);
    }
    return Ok(); 
}
```

For some strange reason the `tenantbranding` parameter is null in the Api Post Method. There is something wrong with the ModelBinding from Web Controller to Api Controller.

This is how my TenantBranding model(Api) looks like:

```
public class TenantBranding
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FormFile> LogoFile { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FormFile> BackgroundFile { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my TenantBranding in Web look like:

```
public class TenantBranding
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile LogoFile { get; set; }
    public IFormFile BackgroundFile { get; set; }
}
```

But the `tenantBranding` parameter in the API method is showing null, so I am not sure why this is happening? May it be related to `IFormFile`?

Answer (score 0):

At first try to add name attribute to your inputs.

```
<input asp-for="BackgroundFile" type="file" name="BackgroundFile" class="form-control-file" id="backgroundFileUrl" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
```

But i suggest you go other way and use ajax request for your api controller:

```
$(form).on("submit", function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"api/controller/action",
       type:"POST",
       //here will be your data from FORM
       data:{
                TenantId:$("#tenantid input id").val(),
                LogoFile :$("#LogoFile input id").val(),
                BackgroundFile :$("#BackgroundFile input id").val(),                
            },
      content-type:"application/json",
      success:function(response){// do on success},
      error:function(){// do somesthig on error}
    });
})
```

When you submit form, js send post request to api controller. This is better way to use WebApi.